# Non-trivial goto use (might beat compiler)

Tags: c, optimization, goto

I had a piece of code that was like this:

```
f += .001f; //Only needs to be executed when loop executes at least one iteration, but does no harm if incremented without entering the loop
while(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
    if(something) {
        //code
        continue;
    }
    //more code
}
```

The only way I found to make this code more efficient (by eliminating unnecessary increments of f) was to use goto.

```
if(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
    f += .001f;

loop:
    if(something) {
        //code
        if(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
            goto loop;
        }
        else {
            goto loop_end;
        }
    }
    //more code
    if(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
            goto loop;
    }
}
loop_end:
```

Even though this is a simple optimization, I don't think the compiler can easily detect this. Is it really non-trivial for the compiler to perform?

Comment: Why are you using `goto` - that went away with the ark

Comment: Instead of the `goto`, why not just add the loop inside the `if`?

Comment: How is this an optimization?

Comment: @melpomene If you are talking about the code's length, this is what the loop looks like in assembly, once it is compiled anyways.

Comment: I'm not talking about length.

Comment: @melpomene But it is an optimization, even if it doesn't look like it.

Comment: I didn't ask whether it is an optimization; I asked how.

Comment: Have you done any measurements on the original code (under optimization) versus the modified code?  Was the difference measurable?  Separately, but much more importantly, the increment to `f` is done differently in the two fragments.  Which is correct?  Or doesn't it matter?  If it doesn't matter, don't fret.  If it matters, do it the correct way.  But avoid the `goto` like the plague it is.  You don't need to use any `goto` to get the correct result, whichever way is correct.

Comment: @melpomene It prevents an if statement from being used and/or f from being needlessly incremented.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The difference in the increment does not matter. "f" can be incremented every time the function is called, or just when the loop is run.

Comment: @Cppplus1 OK, but is incrementing `f` actually slower than the additional jump?

Comment: @melpomene Where is the additional jump?

Comment: @Cppplus1 Well, you're either duplicating the loop condition or adding an additional jump to it.

Comment: @melpomene The "if" replaces the first loop condition, while the goto checks replace the beginning of the second loop iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that just

```
if (anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
    f += .001f;
    do {
        if(something) {
            //code
            continue;
        }
        //more code
    } while(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary);
}
```

?

Comment: Or even `if (something) { /* code */ } else { /* more code */ }` as the loop body; not continue needed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I accidentally left the continue there from a time when it was actually needed.

Answer (score 2):

In this way you need no `goto`s, and the compiler may be able to optimize it.

```
if(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
    f += .001f;
    // Tag loop:
    while (true) {
        if(something) {
            //code
            if(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        //more code
        if(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}
// Tag loop_end:
```

The main logical structure remains unchanged, but there's no more `goto`s.

Comment: Perhaps a Boolean variable instead of continue and break.

Comment: @EdHeal That'd require more changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
    f += .001f;

   while(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) {
       if(something) {
           //code
           if(anIndex < aVaryingBoundary) continue;
           else break;
        }
        //more code
    }
}
```